# Best data provider for calculations in large vector files

Tags: qgis, python, postgis, pyqgis

I am building a QGIS plugin to read text files, convert them to vector files (100,000 to 1,000,000 features; ~5 numeric attributes) and display an additional attribute on a subset of the base vector file.

At the moment, I am loading the base QgsVectorLayer in the memory, then making a copy of a subset in the memory and adding the field/column.  The attribute to be appended is loaded into a numpy array, then updated in the copy.  Everything is done in the memory.  The process is slow though and I can see requesting and setting attributes are the main bottlenecks.

The additional data to be displayed is updated frequently (by the plugin itself).

Would it be faster to process and update the data on an external data provider (e.g. text file with WKT, or PostGIS), setting the attribute there, and then refreshing the source in QGIS?  Or is the QGIS memory faster than external processing + source refreshing?

(Note: the attribute requests and updates have already been optimized to operate on the least possible amount of data).

Comment: When doing this in Esri I find it best to import the table to Microsoft (JET) Access database (personal geodatabase).. this helps find bad rows and fix anomalies, which are hopefully few or none. Importing from the database to features is considerably quicker than from CSV but for *real* speed read the text directly with python as a textfile... just don't try to read the whole file if it's bigger than half to 3/4 your installed (available) RAM.

Comment: For such a tast I would use Postgresql with the copy command. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-copy.htmland then PostGIS functions for setting up the geometries.